# "Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction" for simple AirDropper contract

Tags: tokens, airdrop

I try to use simple AirDrop contract taken from https://github.com/omisego/airdrop/blob/master/contracts/Airdropper.sol -
https://gist.github.com/Gim6626/083d556e0a41da5172de0c49ffd64577 .

It deployes successfully using Remix, but when I try to use it and call `multisend` function I get error "gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction".

Here is data that I pass to function:

- `"0x955fe846c726d5e4aa0a9eea65417dc7394e8dbf"`
- `["0x4fB302f34b3bD02E742B532f266D8853258567cd", "0x4fB302f34b3bD02E742B532f266D8853258567cd"]`
- `[1, 1]`

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Did you assign enough tokens to the contract? Do you have a transaction hash?

Comment: @Ismael, my balance is 146034.564 * 10^18

Comment: @Ismael, oh, got what you meant. No. I haven't send any tokens to contract. Looks like this is my error?

Comment: I'd say it is very likely. The contract Airdroper uses `token.transfer()`, meaning it transfer from the contract account not the sender. But without a transaction hash is hard to say exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @Ismael, correct, this was an error, thanks. I send tokens to contract and then was able to multisend tokens from contract. So obvious, shame on me :)

Comment: @Ismael, you could make an answer based on comments and I'll approve it.